# Angular 1.6.4 How to detect changes in no-bindings properties of components

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-1.6

Maybe someone know how to solve that problem:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.component('myComponent', {
    controller: function () {
        this.prop1 = 1;
    },
    templateUrl: 'template.html'
}
```

So $watch() is not enable for new version. $onChanges() - not work because this is inner property. Can have someone solution to resolve this problem? Thank's for your help.

Comment: This is a totally different question, In my code I try to avoid any bindings.

Comment: *"$watch() is not enable for new version"* - what do you mean?

Comment: try to use $watch in Angular 1.6 component's controller)

Comment: How about defining your own property on the controller class and using the setter to detect changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
angular.module('app.components', [])
.component('changeHandler', {
  controller: function ChangeHandlerController() {
    $onChanges: function (changes) {
      if (changes.canChange) 
       this.performActionWithValueOf(changes.canChange);
    };
  },
  bindings: {
    canChange: '<'
  },
  templateUrl: 'change-handler.html'
});
```

Comment: Yes it will be work, but I want to avoid bindings in this component. I need something like $watch

Comment: this._scope.$watch(() => {
    return this.items;
  },
  (newVal, oldVal) => {
    // Do what you have to here
  });